# ASP.Net Method doesn't get called via JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I tried to make a JSON request to get my data in the background, I took one of my colleagues works as an example. The first result/method is my colleagues, the other one is mine. The problem is that my method doesn't even get called neither an alert pops up.

I can't see any significant difference, please help me:

The ASPX:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    
    function UpdateSettings() {
        var result = $.getJSON('GetProgressMessage?uploaderId=111&iId=1&fileName=test', function (data) { alert(data); }, 'json');
        var result2 = $.getJSON('GetCustomerUploadSettings?customerId=1', function (data) { alert(data.Name); }, 'json'); 
        alert('test');
    }
</script>
```

First method:

```
[NoCache]  
public ActionResult GetProgressMessage(string uploaderId, short iId, string fileName)  
{  
    //some stuff before   
    return this.Json(messageObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
}
```

Second method:

```
[NoCache]
public ActionResult GetCustomerUploadSettings(int customerId)
{
    return this.Json(new { Name = "test" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Of course both methods are in the same class.

Comment: Is the `UpdateSettings` function ever being invoked? Have you checked in the browser's debugger whether you get an exception?

Comment: Of course, the Method above runs in its Breakpoints, and the alert at the bottom of the script also pops up... only not my line :S

Comment: What is `//some stuff before`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller class

```
public JsonResult YourMethodName()
{
    JsonResult json = new JsonResult();
    json.Data = new { OBJECT_TO_RETURN };
    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could open dev tools in browser and view more details. For firefox - Firebug. Chrome and IE have their own tools. Press F12 and reload page.

Comment: At what exactly do i have to look at? 
I tried it out and it ran in the breakpoint i set at the javascript line, but if i step into there is only some not understandable json code...

Comment: No Errors, but i found the solution (i'll post it)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the routing doesn't work. Did you look in the Global.asax.cs file to see if your collegue created a custom route to get to the method?

Comment: I searched in the whole solution, the Methodname is never be used again.. (Except the one aspx file it originally get used)

Comment: Then try and add your method to the routing. It could be that another route "catches" your call.